# Numerical reconstruction of Einstein's field equations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations, general-relativity

A few analytic solutions are known to the Einstein field equations:

$$ R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R - kT_{\mu\nu} = 0$$

Taking a preexisting analytic solution such as Schwarzchild's solution:

$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{bmatrix} (1 - \frac{2m}{r}) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{1}{(1 - \frac{2m}{r})} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -r^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -r^2\sin^2\theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Suppose we now delete a single arbitrary $2\times2\times 2\times 2$ grid locations' known $g_{\mu\nu}$ value.

By what systematic method can we numerically recover the correct identical 10 numeric values of $g_{\mu\nu}$ in this grid, knowing only all of their neighboring points' analytic values except this $2\times 2\times 2\times 2$ hole, forbidding any use of the analytic recipe that generates this numerical field?

Comment: There are a lot of implicit assumptions here and not all of them are clear. The question asks about a grid, but this grid is not introduced in any way. Further, if one wants to talk about a numerical version/approximation to Einstein's equations, one has to be specific. There is a whole field of Numerical Relativity devoted to figuring out how to properly approach Einstein's equations numerically.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine the question is related to numerical solutions to relativity. It's posed here as a boundary value problem to the EFE in its original form. I believe that the ADM form of the EFE can reduce the second order differential equations to first order, which makes it more computable, is anyone familiar with how this is achieved in ADM?

Comment: The use of approximation methods for the Einstein equations is complicated by their lack of linearization stability in situations such as the one you describe - refer J.H. Arms and J.E Marsden, _The absence of Killing fields is necessary for the linearization stability of Einstein's equations_, Indiana Univ. Math. J. 28 (1979), 119-125.

Comment: @James There are more problems with your question, but a big one if you don't realize it is that there is no "original form" of the numerical EFE. That's why one needs to be more specific.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine the grid construction used is the standard numerical cubic grid, say 100x100x100x100. $R_{\mu\nu} - \frac{1}{2}g_{\mu\nu}R - kT_{\mu\nu} = 0$ is implemented directly as 10 simultaneous equations to be solved per grid point (in the manner of a standard Gauss-Seidel grid with spacing $h$ for boundary value problems). Could you elaborate as to what are the problems in this construction, please?

Comment: @James The problem is that you didn't include any of this information, which still seems to me incomplete, in your question. ([How to ask.](https://mathoverflow.net/help/how-to-ask)) Probably the best answer you can get at this point is to pick up a textbook level treatment of Mathematical Relativity (of which I think there's already more than one).

Comment: Mathematical Relativity => Numerical Relativity (sorry, force of habit)

Answer (score 1):

These four lectures by Frans Pretorius may be what you're looking for (#1 - https://youtu.be/Q3QLWCFJPiA).  He describes the (many) issues arising when tackling the Einstein equations via numerical approximation.

Among another things, he describes the numeric treatment of spherically symmetric solutions in the ADM formulation (#2 - https://youtu.be/wOXXUJfHHpg).

[As for the "few" analytic solutions, you may wish to review the book by H. Stephani et al., *Exact Solutions to Einstein's Field Equations* Second Edition, CUP 2003. A mere 600+ pages ...]

Comment: thank you for the reference, am looking through them now. I seem able to solve a single unknown grid point (10 variables) using many attempts of Newton's iteration method. For 2 grid points (20 unknowns and finite difference dependencies among some of those 20 variables) no solution is found so far. Can a boundary value problem of non-linear equations in principle be cast into a simultaneous equations problem with $10n$ variables?